# CSQL code in vb6 for displaying data between two dates?

Tags: sql, vb6

```
Set COUNTER_RS = New Recordset
    COUNTER_RS.Open "Select * from TT_COUNTER where Trans_dt >'" + Format(mskFdate.Text, "mm-dd-yyyy") + "' and Trans_dt <='" + Format(mskTdate.Text, "mm-dd-yyyy") + "'  and Receipt_No like 'A%' and Head_Details='MED' order by Receipt_No", db, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
    MEDI = 0
If COUNTER_RS.RecordCount > 0 Then
    While COUNTER_RS.EOF = False
        MEDI = Val(COUNTER_RS!Rate)
        COUNTER_RS.MoveNext
    Wend
End If
```

Cant find the correct amount between two dates, please help with the code?

[image]

Comment: cant find the correct amount between two dates,please help with the code?

Comment: I create a [SQL Server Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5cc3c) for your sample data - Now we need to know what do you want exactly as result!? -HTH ;).

Comment: Note: Filtering dates need date format like [This sample Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/58d16/1) ;).

Comment: I'm not sure if it will make any difference, but you are formatting your date as mm-dd-yyyy and the dates are being displayed as dd-mm-yyyy.  The other thing to take into consideration is what is the column trans_dt defined as?

Comment: What does this have to do with VB6?